# R: How to split list into several numbers and do the calculation?

Tags: r, list

my data is like:
-3+2
41-12
after separating each part by using the following code:
eg.

`text = '-3+2'`

```
pattern = '-?\\d+'
matches = gregexpr(pattern, text)
a=regmatches(text, matches)
```

I got a list of "numbers"

```
a
[[1]]
[1] "-3" "2"
```

what if i want to add -3 and 2 together? eg(-3+2)=-1
because the result above is a list, so as.numeric does not work...
many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bad form in general, but I think the simplest approach is to use `eval` and `parse` in these cases and completely skip the regex:

```
text = c("-3+2", "99+44-100")
sapply(text, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
#      -3+2 99+44-100 
#        -1        43
```

If you dislike the names on the vectors you can instead do:

```
unname(sapply(text, function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
# [1] -1 43
```

Answer (score 0):

in your particular case (2 numbers):

`as.integer(a[[1]][1]) + as.integer([[1]][2])`

More generally:

`sum(sapply(a[[1]], as.integer))`

Answer (score 0):

or from your list, after parsing:

```
sapply(a, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```